# Call 5 sh scripts from main sh script

Tags: python, cluster-computing, hpc, lsf

I would like some help on how to set up properly a complicated job on a HPC. So, at some point in my python code I want to submit a job by using os.system("bsub -K < mama.sh") , I fould that the -K arg would actually wait for the job to end before continuing. So now I want from this mama.sh script to call 5 other jobs (kid1.sh, kid2.sh ... kid5.sh)  that would run in parallel (to reduce computational time). Each one of these 5 children scripts will run a python piece of code.  mama.sh should wait until all 5 other jobs have finished before continuing.

I thought of something like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
#BSUB -q hpc
#BSUB -J kids[1-5]
#BSUB -n 5
#BSUB -W 10:00
#BSUB -R "rusage[mem=6GB]"
#BSUB -R "span[hosts=1]"
# -- end of LSF options --

module load python3/3.8
python3 script%Ι.py
  ORRR
python3 script1.py
python3 script2.py
python3 script3.py
python3 script4.py
python3 script5.py
```

Maybe the above doesn't make sense at all though. Is there any way to actually do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As is know to me, you can accomplish the goal in different level.

By two easy ways:

1. parallel your python code by import `multiprocessing`
2. parallel your shell script by `&`, command can be executed in the background.

```
    python3 script1.py &
    python3 script2.py
```